# AWS Codebuild to support GitHub releases

Tags: github, webhooks, aws-codebuild, github-release

Can you please help me to figure out how I can customize the Codebuild Webhook to be triggered once a GitHub releases is published, I couldn't find it online.

I cannot use CodePipeline as it's not yet supported under the me-south-1 region.

thank you

Comment: There is no such hook event supported as of now. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/github-webhook.html

But you can trigger on the commit message. As a hack, you can make a dummy commit with a custom message to include some release convention to trigger tohebuild. I wouldn't recommend doing it.